# How to create a test account for development purpose

Tags: facebook, testing

I want to create a test account for creating a application. How should I go about it? I referred to a tutorial and it seems like I will be needing an application id and a secret to create an account. I have read the doc page for Test users and could not make much sense. Would be a great help if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Stackoverflow != Facebook Support

Comment: It's poorly phrased, but there is a test users API. That said, it's really easy to find info about, so maybe the OP hasn't tried anything

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a facebook application first:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/

then add test users to the application:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

However I suspect this kind of "test user" isn't what you actually mean/need. You have to use your personal profile to set up the app and do the majority of your testing with - you aren't permitted to create more than one real profile. If you put your new app into sandbox mode then everything will be hidden anyway.

If you are new to facebook dev, maybe spend some time reading the documentation and looking through the examples first.
https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: facebook revokes me when i try to create an app. They claim that my account is a fake and prevent me from going any further. Hence, I got no app id and secret and I think both are required when using Facebook's PHP library. Browsing the web, I came to know that facebook offers developers a test account for the purposes of development. I assumed that app development could be done only through a test account. Now again, since I cannot get the id and secret, how can I go about this?

Comment: You can't. You need to use your personal facebook account to develop on. What message do you get when you try to create an app? Maybe you just need to get verified?

Comment: There's either an appeals form or a link to where to add your credit card / phone number on that error message - follow those instructions